# Delete characters from a string and convert to date

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I am building a webscraper to get info on tennis players.
It's a start from the ground up project and I am currently experiencing an issue. I am storing the player data in a dictionary with the following lines:

```
player = {}
player['first'] = soup.select('.first-name')[0].text
player['last'] = soup.select('.last-name')[0].text
player['dob'] = soup.select('.table-birthday')[0].text
```

then I get this result:

> {'first': 'Roger', 'last': 'Federer', 'dob':
>   '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(1981.08.08)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'}

How do I get the date of birth to a normal date that I can use?
the scraped website is:
http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/players/roger-federer/f324/overview

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = {'first': 'Roger', 'last': 'Federer',
     'dob': '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(1981.08.08)\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'}

datetime.strptime(d['dob'][d['dob'].find('(')+1:d['dob'].find(')')], '%Y.%m.%d')

# datetime.datetime(1981, 8, 8, 0, 0)
```

**Explanation**

- `d['dob'][d['dob'].find('(')+1:d['dob'].find(')')]` extracts the part of the string between parentheses.
- `datetime.strptime` is used to convert the string into a `datetime` object.

Comment: That is actually quite awesome! Thank you so much. A follow-up question if I may. When I extract the coach, I get: 'coach': '\r\n\t\t\tIvan Ljubicic and Severin Lüthi\r\n\t\t'. How do I remove the \r\n\t part? With re???

Comment: @JoostvandenOever, I'm sure it's possible with `re`, but that would be a slightly different solution to mine! Feel free to accept this one (tick on left) if it helped and start a new question for this problem.

Comment: I figured that one out by doing some googling!